# How can i loop over jquery code ? When i code it showing following error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to display list of posts with sorting filter and pagination. It's working when i code repeatedly for container as `#container1`, `#container2` and so on what i want is to loop all the container to show sorting filter using mixitup and pagination using simplePagination js

**JQuery, Javascript**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
    // First Column Pagination start from here

    for(var i=0; i< 3; i++){

      function sw_show_pagination(){
        jQuery(function(jQuery) {
          var pageParts = jQuery(".itemContainer-"+i+" .mix");
          var numPages = pageParts.length;
          var perPage = 10;
          pageParts.slice(perPage).hide();
          jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination({
            items: numPages,
            itemsOnPage: perPage,
            prevText:"",
            nextText:"",
            cssStyle: "compact-theme",
            onPageClick: function(pageNum) {
              var start = perPage * (pageNum - 1);
              var end = start + perPage;
              pageParts.hide().slice(start, end).show();
            }
          });
        });
      } //end show pagination

      sw_show_pagination();

      // First Column MixItUp start from here
      var containerEl+i = document.querySelector('[data-ref="itemContainer-'+i+'"]');
      var config+i = { controls: { scope: 'local' } , callbacks: {
        onMixStart: function(state,futureState ){
          jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination('destroy');
        },
        onMixEnd: function(state, futureState){
          jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination('redraw');
        }
      }};

      var mixer+i = mixitup(containerEl+i,config+i);

    }

  });
```

> console error SyntaxError: unexpected token: '+'

on line 
[image]

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: how it is not clear i just want to loop over jquery code to remove errors in console.

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas I've added an answer. You are not allowed to use a + in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to use a '+' in the variable name.

Change the following:

containerEl+i

config+i

mixer+i

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
// First Column Pagination start from here

for(var i=0; i< 3; i++){

function sw_show_pagination(){
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
var pageParts = jQuery(".itemContainer-"+i+" .mix");
var numPages = pageParts.length;
var perPage = 10;
pageParts.slice(perPage).hide();
jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination({
items: numPages,
itemsOnPage: perPage,
prevText:"",
nextText:"",
cssStyle: "compact-theme",
onPageClick: function(pageNum) {
var start = perPage * (pageNum - 1);
var end = start + perPage;
pageParts.hide()
.slice(start, end).show();
}
});
});

} //end show pagination

sw_show_pagination();

// First Column MixItUp start from here
var containerEli = document.querySelector('[data-ref="itemContainer-'+i+'"]');
var configi = { controls: { scope: 'local' } , callbacks: {
onMixStart: function(state,futureState ){
jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination('destroy');
},
onMixEnd: function(state, futureState){
jQuery(".page-nav-"+i).pagination('redraw');
}
} };
var mixeri = mixitup(containerEli,configi);

}

});
```

Comment: Only error I get now is the 'mixitup' not existing, but i assume you have a function elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks sparky the above code hiding the pagination and stops sorting and showing error 

TypeError: o is undefined[Learn More]
jquery.simplePagination.js:280:5
[MixItUp] WARNING: An operation was requested but the MixItUp instance was busy. The operation was rejected because the queue is full or queuing is disabled.
mixitup.min.js:17:31770
TypeError: o is undefined[Learn More] jquery.simplePagination.js:280:5
[MixItUp] WARNING: An operation was requested but the MixItUp instance was busy. The operation was rejected because the queue is full or queuing is disabled.

Comment: here is the link Sparky of my website.

[link](https://shinefirst.000webhostapp.com/sleep-or-woke-page/)

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas I didn't get those errors myself, because your mixitup() is not in your question. But I'm sure you can figure the rest out, right? Just avoid illegal characters in the variable name. Best practice is to stick with lowercase a-z and Underscores_